# Can't scroll vertically in UITableView containing custom cells with horizontal scrollview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

If my drag touch originates outside of the cell's horizontal scrollview, then I am able to drag the tableview up and down.

But if an attempt to drag the tableview up or down begins in the cell's horizontal scrollview, then the cell's scrollview intercepts the touch and doesn't do anything.

**How can I pass the vertical drag from the cell's scrollview through to the parent tableView?**

Comment: Using a scrollview inside of a table view is discouraged by Apple, I would look at solving your problem differently. Table view inherits from a scrollview, so as you are seeing, touch events will be difficult to manage with your current setup.

Comment: Dreaming In Binary, would you recommend UIPanGestureRecognizer instead? Does that pass through the touch to the scrollview?

Comment: In your horizontal cell's scroll view do you disable vertical scroll setting?

Comment: I couldn't find a setting for that. Please let me know if there is one. To stop it from scrolling vertically, I would setContentOffset for y to 0 inside of scrollViewDidScroll